# how to detect part of an Image taken from the camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image-processing, image-recognition

hi i would like to detect part of the Image taken from the camera, on a toffee wrapper.

Is there a possibility that this app will not work(not recognize image) under any circumstance? For eg. dim light, bright sun light, wrapper not held correctly and so on...Also, do i need any marker?

I did some research and found that few APIs could detect images with predefined accuracy threshold (like 60% match == successful) but **what i don't understand is how do i create part of UIImage to match with picture taken from camera?**

Please point me in the right direction... what am i looking for here?

If possible this thing could be immensely useful for iOS developer community, as there are large number of apps possible with this concept.

**i want to detect the coco bean image and dark in this image**

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you post a picture showing what you're trying to detect in an image?

Comment: added image to my question please see